# Client.py doesnt connect to server.py

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have problem with python3 network (socket) programming. The problem is, when i run server.py everything is good. Than i open client.py, it must connect to server.py but it doesnt connect. It stays for 5-15 seconds then it gives error about connection. I give access python to use network. I dont know why its not working.

Server.py codes:

```py
import socket

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 80

Buffer_Size = 1024

socket.bind((host, port))
socket.listen(1)
connectionNumber = 1
print("\n" + "[SERVER] Port" + str(port) + "opened. Connections are listening..." + "\n")

while True:
    print("\n" + "*"*50)
    print("[SERVER] Waitong connection {}...".format(connectionNumber))
    conn, addr = socket.accept()
    print("[SERVER] Connected to {}".format(addr))
    print("[SERVER] Receiving bytes...")
    while True:
        msgFromClient = socket.recv(Buffer_Size)
        if not msgFromClient:
            print("[SERVER] No message received.")
            break
        
        print("[CLIENT]: {}".format(msgFromClient))
        print("[SERVER] Message received, buffer emptied. " + connectionNumber + "Closing Connection...")
        conn.send(str(msgFromClient) + ". You are the client. Thanks for connecting!")
    conn.close()
    print("[SERVER] Connection closed...")
    connectionNumber += 1
```

client.py codes:

```py
import getpass

pcName = getpass.getuser()

import socket

clientName = socket.gethostname()
clientIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

sendingMessageToServer = pcName +"___" + clientName + "___"+ clientIP

import socket

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 80
Buffer_Size = 1024
clientSocket.connect((host, port)) 

print("Sending message: {}".format(sendingMessageToServer))

clientSocket.send(sendingMessageToServer)

print("Message Sended Succesfully!")

messageFromServer = clientSocket.recv(Buffer_Size)

print("[SERVER] Received message: {}".format(messageFromServer))

print("[CLIENT SERVER] Message received.. Closing connection...")

clientSocket.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should change your port 80 because it is used by http connection. Maybe your system is taking it over. Set for example port 8001. In `server.py` you get incoming data from created `conn` object, not `socket`:

```
msgFromClient = conn.recv(Buffer_Size)
```

Also data received or sent through socket should be `bytes` type, not `str` therefore you should change all `recv` and `send` parameters to bytes, for example:

```
conn.send(msgFromClient + b". You are the client. Thanks for connecting!")
```

or in `client.py`:

```
clientSocket.send(sendingMessageToServer.encode())
```